# How to restart a loop by condition

Tags: python, for-loop

I have code as:

```py
for i in [data1, data2]:
    pbest_A = i.iloc[:, 0]
    pbest_B = i.iloc[:, 3]

    gbest_score_cycle = i['score'].max()  # max score in cycle
    gbest_score = np.where(gbest_score_cycle > gbest_score, gbest_score_cycle, gbest_score)  # update gbest score
    if gbest_score == gbest_score_cycle:  # row of gbest 
        gbest = i.loc[i['score'].idxmax()] 

    gbest_A = gbest[0]
    gbest_B = gbest[3]

    save_A = []
    save_B = []

    for j in range(5):
        R1 = random.uniform(0,1)
        R2 = random.uniform(0,1)

        Xid_A = New_Xid_A
        Xid_B = New_Xid_B
        Vid_A = New_Vid_A
        Vid_B = New_Vid_B

        New_Vid_A = w*Vid_A + c1*R1*(pbest_A[i]- Xid_A) + c2*R2*(gbest_A - Xid_A)
        New_Vid_B = w*Vid_B + c1*R1*(pbest_B[i] - Xid_B) + c2*R2*(gbest_B - Xid_B)
        New_Xid_A= Xid_A + New_Vid_A
        New_Xid_B= Xid_B + New_Vid_B
        # get result: New_Xid_A, New_Xid_B
        # *** if New_Xid_A > 10 or New_Xid_B > 20, restart this loop (same j in [for j in range(5)])

        save_A.append(New_Xid_A)
        save_B.append(New_Xid_B)

    print(save_A)
    print(save_B)
```

I've search for this kind of problem. And I'm thinking about how to use `while` in the for loop. Cause now my problem is when the condition conform, then restart the loop(and do not append to the save_A & save_B). Is there any way to done it?

Comment: You might have a typo in `daat1` instead of `data1`

Comment: use while loop and if condition reset index and continue

Comment: Does the inner loop `for j in range(5)` use some outer scope variables (from outer loop) ? Also, what is `process` here, `Process` instance or just some function?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes, there's some variables from the outer loop

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest `process` are some math formula and contains random function in

Comment: @xiumpt, add more code to show the context of each loop

Comment: Does your for loop move to the next element when the inner loop resets, or it continues till you finish the inner loop @xiumpt

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest updated full code of the loop.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh it will continues till finish the inner loop

Comment: Hi @xiumpt I have added one possible approach in my answer, please check the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Closure"* function + *"Exception"* approach (pythonic):

```
def outer():
    # ... all the needed variables

    for i in [data1, data2]:
        pbest_A = i.iloc[:, 0]
        pbest_B = i.iloc[:, 3]

        gbest_score_cycle = i['score'].max()  # max score in cycle
        gbest_score = np.where(gbest_score_cycle > gbest_score, gbest_score_cycle, gbest_score)  # update gbest score
        if gbest_score == gbest_score_cycle:  # row of gbest 
            gbest = i.loc[i['score'].idxmax()]

        gbest_A = gbest[0]
        gbest_B = gbest[3]

        save_A, save_B = [], []

        def inner():
            try:
                for j in range(5):
                    R1 = random.uniform(0, 1)
                    R2 = random.uniform(0, 1)

                    Xid_A = New_Xid_A
                    Xid_B = New_Xid_B
                    Vid_A = New_Vid_A
                    Vid_B = New_Vid_B

                    New_Vid_A = w * Vid_A + c1 * R1 * (pbest_A[i] - Xid_A) + c2 * R2 * (gbest_A - Xid_A)
                    New_Vid_B = w * Vid_B + c1 * R1 * (pbest_B[i] - Xid_B) + c2 * R2 * (gbest_B - Xid_B)
                    New_Xid_A = Xid_A + New_Vid_A
                    New_Xid_B = Xid_B + New_Vid_B

                    # get result: New_Xid_A, New_Xid_B
                    if New_Xid_A > 10 or New_Xid_B > 20:
                        raise ValueError    # terminate current function call

                    save_A.append(New_Xid_A)
                    save_B.append(New_Xid_B)

            except ValueError:
                inner()     # back to the same function with a new call

        inner()

        print(save_A)
        print(save_B)

outer()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use two while loops, the first while loop is an infinite loop which breaks and moves on to the next element in the for loop, only when the inner while loop, which runs till 5 is done.

The code goes as follows

```
for i in [data1, data2]:

    #Outer while loop runs till inner while loop is finished
    while True:
        j = 0
        #Inner while loop
        while j < 5:
            #If condition is met, reset inner counter and break inner while loop
            if New_Xid_A > 10 or New_Xid_B > 20:
                j = 0
                break
            j += 1

        #If inner while loop is successful, break out of infinite loop
        if j == 5:
            break
```